# jquery validation normalizer - the value which has trim applied is not being sent to server

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Applying the [Normalizer method in jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/normalizer/) to trim whitespace from username and password fields. However the result sent back to the server does not have the trim applied. I understand I should I never assume but just a question out of curiosity is this the expected result?

> Eg: Use the values inside the quotes Username:"   test  " Password:" C
>   F1234  "
>
> After normalization from console.log values are
>
> Username:"test" Password:"C F1234"
>
> But with `submitHandler` the `form.submit()` sends the values as
>   inputted by the user.

Have I implemented this incorrectly?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#login-form").validate({
  rules: {
   username:{
    required:true,
    normalizer:function(value){
                    console.log('user pre-trim:'+value);
                    console.log('user post-trim:'+$.trim(value));
     return $.trim(value);
    },
    email:true,
   },
   password:{
    required:true,
    normalizer:function(value){
                    console.log('pwd pre-trim:'+value);
                    console.log('pwd post-trim:'+$.trim(value));
     return $.trim(value);
    },
    
   },
   
  },
  errorContainer: "#errorMessageContainer",
  errorLabelContainer: "#errorMessageContainer ul",
  errorElement: "li",
  messages: {
   username:{
    required:"Email cannot be left empty",
    email:"Must be an Email address"
   },
   password: {
    required: "Password Cannot Be Left Empty",
    
   }
  }
  ,
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            //Can something be done here?
            console.log('invalidContainer');
  },
  submitHandler: 
   function(form) {
    form.submit();
   }
 });
 
 displayErrorContainer();
   
});


function displayErrorContainer(){
 var child = $("#errorMessageContainer").children("ul").html();
 console.log('ftn: msg displayErrorContainer:'+child);
 if(typeof child !== "undefined" && child.length > 0){
  //console.log("show the error-container");
  $("#errorMessageContainer").show();
 }else{
  //console.log("hide the error-container");
  $("#errorMessageContainer").hide();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div id="errorMessageContainer">
  <ul><li>Username and Password do not match</li></ul>
</div>
<form id="login-form" request="POST">
 <input id="username" name="username"  type="text" />
 <input id="password" name="password"  type="password" />
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have I implemented this incorrectly?

[Reading the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/normalizer/):  *"**Doesn't change the elements' value**, it only changes the value used for validation."*

So the answer is 'no'.